# Prettyphoto jQuery - how to include video player on pop up?

Tags: javascript

I have jQuery plugin Prettyphoto on my site and now it open video from youtube chanel on click, but I want do some changes, when pop up is open I need to play video on Video js (it's a video player), so now I have code below, how can I do this?

Comment: add your own custom callback in the plugin itself to play video in videojs.

Comment: How ??)) Can you help with examples

Answer (score 2):

Open your prettyphoto.js and search for the following line in the code

```
if(settings.autoplay) movie += "&autoplay=1";
```

and change it to add your videojs `play()` to play the video like this and also set `autoplay=true` in the prettyphoto initialization code.

```
if(settings.autoplay) {
    movie += "&autoplay=1";
    myVideJsPlayer = videojs('example_video_1');
    myVideJsPlayer();
}
```

Comment: Thank's! You helped me